# Can I get a value returned from Close handler of a RadWindow?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web, telerik, radwindow

I have a radwindow and it displays under a dialog. As you know, after closing this dialog, its ​Close handler function will be hit. In there, I return a boolean value. 
And my problem is that I want to get the return value directly from the Close handler **without using any global flags**.

Please reference the snippet code below to get more detail.

Function used for showing the dialog:

```
function showDialog() {
        var url = "ChildPage.aspx";
        var wnd = window.radopen(url, 'Child Dialog');
        wnd.set_modal(true);
        wnd.setSize(400, 120);
        wnd.set_minHeight(300);
        wnd.set_minWidth(100);
        wnd.set_destroyOnClose(true);
        wnd.set_keepInScreenBounds(true);
        wnd.set_overlay(false);
        wnd.set_visibleStatusbar(false);
        wnd.set_visibleTitlebar(true);
        wnd.add_close(closeChildDialogHandler); //closeChildDialogHandler is Close handler
        wnd.set_behaviors(Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Move + Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Close + Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Resize);
        wnd.show();
        wnd.center();
    }
```

And its Close handle function. As you see, I want to return **true|false** value in this handler.

```
function closeChildDialogHandler(sender, args) {
        var flag = false;
        var objConfirmSQ = args.get_argument();
        if (objConfirmSQ != null && typeof objConfirmSQ['returnValue'] != "undefined") {
            console.log("objConfirmSQ['returnValue'] = " + objConfirmSQ['returnValue']);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

OK, and is there any way I can receive the **true|false** value from the handler like this:

```
function myFunction(){
  var myVar = closeChildDialogHandler(unknown_param, unknown_param) //Not sure about this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An abstract solution would be:

> Callback mechanism is a good alternative to return mechanism.

A more specific solution:
1) Declare a function.

```
childCloseResponseListener = function(myBooleanValue) {
/*Your handling for the boolean value when it gets here*/
}
childCloseResponseListener.bind(this);
```

2) Access it from dialog's close listener

```
childCloseResponseListener(true);
```

OR

```
childCloseResponseListener(false);
```